# IP Cam live video feed using server end to front end C# MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, model-view-controller, ip-camera

Im making a c# mvc app and I have ip cam which is connected via a vpn to server pc. Ip cam is only available when the vpn is connected. Without the vpn i cant code it into view becasue the client end there wont be any vpn. So is there a way to display or transfer that server generated live video feed to a mvc razor page (in client pc)?

Comment: the camera information needs to be served in some fashion. Does the camera currently submit information to your server, or is it online in some fashion?  is there any current way to view this stream? like a url? I can appreciate that I will not be able to connect to it. I think likely, you will need to host, on the server a video feed. this is always available, but may not have live video being supplied ( if vpn is down ). then you have a simpler method to connect your front end to. it would either show, or not show.

Comment: @ThisGuy Cam Info can be served via the server, but the question is how can i transfer the live stream to view

Comment: why do you want to try and switch between two different methods? It should be simpler to server your video from one source and simply serve an empty or offline message when that is appropriate. 1 thing is easier to manage than 2 things, imo.

Comment: I agree with This Guy. If you only control Server and Client but not the connection to the Camera, you cannot magically make pictures appear out of the blue. If the Server can be in both VPN and Public Network, then you can use it as Proxy, but that's about it. If the VPN is gone, it is equal to unplugging the cam.

Comment: @NishanthaMaduranga, it might be a good idea to regroup and re-focus your question. I have a suspicion that you want to know how to set up the server to do this.  I think you may indicate that you can view the cam when it is online by directly connecting client to cam, but you do want to have this set as a proxy style connection, where the client connects to "something" on the server, which then gets it's stream from the cam.  I feel that I am just making a mess of this question that you have :)

Comment: @ThisGuy hello I found this post and what you said is exactly what I have been trying to figure out. I want to 1st add a layer between the client and camera for security  and 2 use this layer to run additional processes on the footage like saving, motion detection, ect... My biggest pain so far has been redirecting a stream from the c# api to the front end. I used ffmpeg convert the footage into hls and was able to play from client but it has horrible latency, I would prefer a little latency as possible. Also I am not sure how I can restrict users without permission from viewing the redirected